# failing form validation forces user to refresh page before submit works

Tags: jquery, html

Because IE < 10 doesn't support the `Required` html form attribute, I had to use jquery to check the form for blank form fields. The problem is, when the user clicks submit and a `Required` error message pops up, they are unable to place a value in the field and click `submit`. Instead, they have to refresh the page in order for the submit button to work again. Is their a way so the user doesn't have to refresh the page after failed validation?

```
$('html body input#create.btn').click(function() {
    $('select').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() < 1) {
            $(this).focus();
            $('#required-warning-label').remove();
            $(this).parent().append('<span id="required-warning-label" class="label label-warning">Required</span>');
            stopsubmit = true;
            return false;
        }
    })
    if (stopsubmit) return false;
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update your code to

```
$('html body input#create.btn').click(function() {
stopsubmit = false;
$('select').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() < 1) {
        $(this).focus();
        $('#required-warning-label').remove();
        $(this).parent().append('<span id="required-warning-label" class="label label-warning">Required</span>');
        stopsubmit = true;
        return false;
    }
})
if (stopsubmit) return false;
})
```

Comment: the first time you posted, it worked. when you had `if (!stopsubmit) return false`

Answer (score 0):

That’s because you never set your `stopsubmit` flag back to false. Do that *before* looping over the select fields with `.each`.

And while you’re at it, make it a *local* variable within the click handler function as well, no need for it to be global.

Comment: New to jquery, how is the variable global?

Comment: Because it is not preceded by the `var` keyword (unless you have done that some place else you have not shown; if you didn’t, then that variable would be undefined in your if statement.) So just put `var stopsubmit = false;` at the beginning of your click handler function.

Answer (score 0):

**maybe if you change this the program will work well:
if (stopsubmit) return false;**

```
  $('html body input#create.btn').click(function() {
   var stopsubmit=false;
        $('select').each(function() {
            if ($(this).val() < 1) {
                $(this).focus();
                $('#required-warning-label').remove();
                $(this).parent().append('<span id="required-warning-label" class="label label-warning">Required</span>');
                stopsubmit = true;
                return false;
            }
        })
       if(stopsubmit==true){

       }else{
        $("your_form_name").submit();
       }
    })
```